# How can I move my Amazon RDS MySql database to Heroku

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I currently have a MySql database in Amazon RDS I'd like to move over to Heroku Postgres. (I would just connect my Heroku app to Amazon RDS, but I don't really want my database to be open to the public).

How can I move my database? I'd imagine:

1. Download from RDS
2. Convert MySql -> Postgres
3. Upload to Heroku

What's typically the best way to do something like this? Do I have to convert the database type?

Comment: Heroku's Postgres offering is "open to the public" - it's protected by a strong password, not networking rules. So, if you're comfortable with Heroku Postgres, you should be comfortable with modifying your RDS to be similarly open. You'll have the same level of security and none of the work of converting your whole DB.

Comment: @ceejayoz That makes sense. So the reason that nobody asks this question is -- there is very little upside to moving a db from AWS to Heroku once your DB is set up on AWS.

Comment: I mean, there are differences between the two. This just isn't one of them. I use Heroku's Postgres offering because I like that I can spin up an isolated instance for their "review apps" and CI pipelines automatically with no work on my end.